# Any tool to monitor nodes?

Tags: node, baker, endorser

Which tools can be used to monitor the tezos node, baker-node, and endorser-node?

If there any tool by community/any other please share the link.

Monitoring the nodes in terms of performance of nodes like endorsement and baking performance as well as the tezos node with tools like prometheus and grafana which gives an alert when a node goes down/missing baker opportunity/missing endorsement.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "monitor". Are you looking for performance metrics to see is it using too much RAM / CPU? Are you looking to monitor RPC traffic to see is it returning errors? etc. Always give examples of what it is you are trying to do

Comment: Made an edit for more clearity